# adding a class to HTML using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SgCpq/), which has a main image and image nav.

I need to wrap a div around the image nav so that i can position it with CSS.

How do i add the class to my HTML?

[My Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgCpq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the question was not clear to me but you can use `wrap`

```
$('img ').wrap('<div class="newClass" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SgCpq/1/

EDIT

```
$('img').filter(function(){return $(this).width()===40;})
.wrap('<div class="newClass" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SgCpq/5/

Comment: P.S. you should have mentioned that you are using an `iframe`

Comment: the image nav are the smaller images in the JSFIDDLE example. How would the jquery know which image to wrap the new class around? and how would it know where to end?

Comment: iframe? no.. the jsfiddle uses an Iframe to display the content... my site does not use an iframe.. :s

Comment: that my friend you will have to tell the jquery `:)` let me see it again

Comment: i'm checking for the `img` that have the `width ===40` you can specify your own criteria

Comment: it works on the jsfiddle but doesnt work on my website. Im placing the jquery code in my template master file. Hmmmm

Comment: are you wrapping you code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: Its not adding the class because there is embeded JS which is creating the 40x40 images. Therefore the class we added gets over-written. I think i need to add the class to a div thats already in the HTML which is NOT code generated.

Comment: no its not over written probably you are calling the `wrap`ing code before the `img` generation code thats why the selector cannot find the `img` with the width 40 try adding the wraping code after the img generation code

Comment: thats the thing, i cant find where the code is being generated. Its probably in a .cs file somewhere.